# Why am I getting WHERE syntax errors on extremely basic queries?

Tags: google-bigquery

Just got started learning BigQuery from the Coursera Google Data Analytics course and was practicing running some queries. However, all of a sudden I started having issues when it came to the WHERE clause in my queries where I'd get a "syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword WHERE at [2:1]". This is my query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM 'bigquery-public-data.london_bicycles.cycle_hire'
WHERE duration >= 12000
```

This should be correct, even when I refer to the solution, it is typed the same way but for whatever reason i get the WHERE syntax error, even on previous lessons where I have ran successful queries, they now give me a syntax error when re-doing them.

Comment: you should use a backtick(`) instead of a single quote(') around a table name.

Comment: Understood, however, despite that, the error lies somewhere with the WHERE clause even though I am unsure of the issue

Comment: Except quote issues,  above query seems have no problem.